# How to link multiple .so files in a C++ Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

My Makefile looks as follows:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g

INCLUDES = -Iinclude/

OBJS = a1.o \
   b1.o

LIBPATH= /usr/lib/<arch>

test-app:$(OBJS)
$(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

%.o : %.cpp
$(CXX) $(INCLUDES) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

I want to link two files lib1.so and lib2.so present in LIBPATH? Can anyone please help me with the syntax?

Comment: This doesn't address your question directly, but are you sure that you want to use make directly? There's a trend in shifting to other (higher level) tools: cmake, scons, etc.

Comment: You want to link them into `test-app`? Are you asking how to link to them at all or how/where to do that in the makefile?

Comment: Etan Reisner : I know the location of .so files to link, I need to know the syntax to link them in Makefile

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
test-app:$(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS) -Lpath_to_your_lib -lyour_libname
```

Also you should use pkg-config to find those variables value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
LIBRARIES= -llib1 -llib2

...
test-app:$(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ -L$(LIBPATH) $(LIBRARIES) $(OBJS)
```

Consider that the arguments order are most of times important since the gcc compiler/linker process the files just one time in the given order and if the order was wrong errors like "Symbol not find" and "undefined reference" will be produced.

Though, I strongly recommend [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) since it's syntax is so easier, more dynamic and It supports many build platforms (IDEs, Compilers, Makefiles, etc.)

**Update:**
This configuration is likely more effective than the above:

```
SHARED_LIBRARIES= -L/path/to/shared_libs -llib1 -llib2
STATIC_LIBRARIES= -L/path/to/static_libs -llib1 -llib2 -L/another/path/to/static_libs -llib3

...
test-app:$(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(STATIC_LIBRARIES) $(SHARED_LIBRARIES) $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea what can I do to link if one of the library is static while other is dynamic?

Comment: It's not really different. Just make sure to have a correct library path for the both static and shared libraries. for example: `STATIC_LIBRARIES= -L/path/to/static_libs -lstatic1 -lstatic2 ....` and also include this variable in the building command: `$(CXX) -o $@ $(LIBRARIES) $(STATIC_LIBRARIES)`